# Excel array Formula that copies only cells containing a string

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, search, indexing

I would prefer to use an excel array formula (but if it can only be done in VBA, so be it) that copies ALL cells from a column array that contains specific text. The picture below shows what I am after and what I have tried. I'm getting close (thanks to similar, but different questions) but can't quite get to where I want. At the moment, I am getting only the first cell instead of all the cells. In my actual application, I am searching through about 20,000 cells and will have a few hundred search terms. I expect most search terms to give me about 8 - 12 cells with that value.

formula I am using:

```
=INDEX($A$4:$A$10,MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(SEARCH($C$1,$A$4:$A$10)),0))
```

[image: Spredsheet Image]

Comment: Why not just use the built in Filter functionality?

Comment: @tigeravatar That works fine for doing a couple of copy and paste sections, but I will be doing this for hundreds of search terms and in my next project, those search terms will change. A programmatic solution will save time in the long run.

Comment: @SethWilliamGregg the Filter function, not the AutoFilter functionality.

Answer (score 1):

How about using FILTER:

```
=FILTER($A$4:$A$10,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1,$A$4:$A$10)))
```

Or... as I generally recommend using Tables... see https://youtu.be/Ss3AY-oJHDo?si=93FfkMlm7d6lGyiZ... You can use Table[Column] reference instead of fixed cell reference:

```
=FILTER(Table1[Array of Strings],ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1,Table1[Array of Strings])))
```

Extra: You can use this for Drop-down list (aka Data Validation as List)... see image below... Simply add Data Validation to cell =$C$5# (notice the '#' on the end which tells Data Validation to use the dynamic array.

```
=$C$5#
```

[image: FILTER + Drop-down]

Answer (score 0):

To make this work efficiently, I recommend having a separate cell holding the results count (I used cell C2) which has this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&C1&"*")
```

Then in cell C4 and copied down use this array formula (The `-3` is just because the header row is row 3.  If the header row was row 1, it would be `-1`):

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>$C$2,"",INDEX($A$4:$A$21000,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1,$A$4:$A$21000)),ROW($A$4:$A$21000)-3),ROW(C1))))
```

I tested this with 21000 rows of data in column A with an average of 30 results per search string and the formula is copied down for 60 cells in column C.  With that much data, this takes about 1-2 seconds to finish recalculating.  Recalculation time can vary widely depending on other factors in your workbook (additional formulas, nested dependencies, use of volatile functions, etc) as well as your hardware.

Alternately, you could just use the built-in Filter functionality, but I hope this helps.

Comment: That seems to work very well. I had seen ROW() used in other similar questions, but couldn't sort out how to use it in this instance

Comment: Don't forget to to tick tiger's answer as it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the ROWS. Put this in C4 and copy down.

`=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,  IF(SEARCH($C$1, $A$4:$A$10)>0, ROW($A$4:$A$10)), ROW($C4)-ROW($A$4)+1), "")`

Array formula so use ctrl-shift-Enter

Comment: When I use this formula in cell range C4:C4 I get: 4,6,7,10, which appears to be the relative index. Ok.. I get it now.

Comment: so: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A, AGGREGATE(15,6, IF(SEARCH($C$1, $A$4:$A$10)>0, ROW($A$4:$A$10)), ROW($C4)-ROW($A$4)+1)), "")`